# org.json.JSONException: No value for item

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

I get a `No value for {"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"}` `JSONException` when I attempt to view data from MySql database using android app.

```
  08-20 04:26:39.396: W/System.err(4732): org.json.JSONException: No value for {"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"}
  08-20 04:26:39.497: W/System.err(4732):   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
  08-20 04:26:39.497: W/System.err(4732):   at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
  08-20 04:26:39.517: W/System.err(4732):   at com.example.phpapp.ViewData$MyTask.doInBackground(ViewData.java:69)
  08-20 04:26:39.577: W/System.err(4732):   at com.example.phpapp.ViewData$MyTask.doInBackground(ViewData.java:1)
  08-20 04:26:39.606: W/System.err(4732):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  08-20 04:26:39.606: W/System.err(4732):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  08-20 04:26:39.631: W/System.err(4732):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  08-20 04:26:39.636: W/System.err(4732):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  08-20 04:26:39.636: W/System.err(4732):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  08-20 04:26:39.636: W/System.err(4732):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

### PHP code

```
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("can't connect");
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("no such db name");
$query = "select username from users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

### jsonArray

```
{"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"}
```

### Android Code

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String str = "";
while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
    s.append(str+"\n");
    mystr = s.toString();
}   

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(mystr);
JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray(mystr);
for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
    st = Jasonobject.getString("username");
    alist.add(str);
}
```

How to Solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in this line

```
 JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray(mystr);
```

Where `mystr={"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"}`    (the data from input stream)

So here you are trying to access a JSON Array with index `mystr` from JSONObject `object`

Which technically never exist  so it is giving the  `JSONException: No value for {"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"}`

**Solution**

Correct PHP code using JJPA's Answer then

use

```
JSONArray Jarray=new JSONArray(mystr);
```

Answer (score 1):

this

`{"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"}`

is not a json array and not even a valid json string.

If this was a json array then it would look like below,

`[{"username":"sara"},{"username":"john"}]`

so you need to have a comma between those objects and FYI json objects will be with `{}` and array's will be in `[]`. So you need to correct the json string and then write the json parsers for that.

Your php code should be modified like below, which prints json array,

```
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("can't connect");
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("no such db name");
$query = mysql_query("select username from users");
$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['col1'] = $row['col1'];// and your respective cols
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: How to get valid json string ?{"username":"sara"}{"username":"john"} comes from above php code.

Comment: Use [this](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) link to check for the correctness of your json string with your json string and `[{"username":"sara"},{"username":"john"}]` and know the results. Read  the messages.

Comment: Use the proper php code which gives you valid json array. Now you are actually printing the values for each loop a json object. I have given you a example php code